# Hamilton's characteristic and principal functions and separability

Tags: classical-mechanics, energy, hamiltonian-formalism, variational-principle, hamiltonian

Just hoping for some clarity regarding Hamilton's characteristic function $W$. When we take a time independent Hamiltonian we can separate the Principal function $S$ up into the characteristic function minus $ht$,  yes I know it's the Legendre transform but,

\begin{equation}
W=S+ht
\end{equation}

Meirovitch in his *Methods of Analytical Dynamics* p 356 gives $h$ as being the Jacobi energy function $h$ as defined in earlier chapters both his and Goldstein's texts.

This is the only time I have seen it being called $h$ rather than the Hamiltonian. I was just wondering if anyone had read through it and perhaps noticed something different in Meirovitch's definition that escapes me. Most authors define these integration constants as the Hamiltonian instead. I know the difference is subtle but it is intriguing as to why he chose $h$ not $H$! Is it just down to how you express the conjugate momenta?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I) Hamilton's characteristic function $W(q,\alpha)$ is usually only defined for systems without explicit time dependence, cf. Refs. 1 and 2. This means that the Hamiltonian $H(q,p)$ is a constant of motion. The constant of motion is usually the *energy* of the system, and it is often denoted with the letter $E$. Ref. 1 uses instead the symbol $\alpha_1$, while Ref. 2 uses the letter $h$.

II) For systems without explicit time dependence, the [Hamilton–Jacobi (HJ) equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamilton%E2%80%93Jacobi_equation) reads

$$\begin{align} -\frac{\partial S(q,\alpha,t)}{\partial t}
~\stackrel{\text{HJ-eq.}}{=}&~
H\left(q,\frac{\partial S(q,\alpha,t)}{\partial q}\right)\cr~=~& \alpha_1.\end{align}\tag{1} $$

One may therefore view Hamilton's characteristic function $W(q,\alpha)$ as an $\alpha_1 \leftrightarrow t$ [Legendre transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_transformation) of Hamilton's principal function $S(q,\alpha,t)$

$$\begin{align} W(q,\alpha)~=~&S(q,\alpha,t)+\alpha_1 t\cr  
~\stackrel{(1)}{=}~&
S(q,\alpha,t) -  t\frac{\partial S(q,\alpha,t)}{\partial t}.\end{align} \tag{2} $$

III) The above is an on-shell formulation. There is a similar story off-shell. (The words *on-shell* and *off-shell* refer to whether the EOMs are satisfied or not.) Let us for definiteness assume Dirichlet boundary conditions

$$ q(t_i)~=~q_i \quad\text{and}\quad q(t_f)~=~q_f \quad\text{fixed}.\tag{3} $$

Although OP seems fully aware of this, let us stress that Hamilton's principal function $S(q,\alpha,t)$ should not be confused with the (off-shell) [action](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_%28physics%29) functional

$$ I[q; t_f,t_i]~:=~ \int_{t_i}^{t_f} L(q,\dot{q},t) ~\mathrm{d}t,\tag{4} $$

nor the (Dirichlet) on-shell action function $S(q_f, t_f; q_i, t_i)$. For more information about the relationship and differences between $S(q,\alpha,t)$, $S(q_f, t_f; q_i, t_i)$, and $I[q; t_i,t_f]$, see e.g. my Phys.SE answers [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/32277/2451) and [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/90857/2451).

Let us emphasize for later comparison that in the [stationary action principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_action) we restrict to virtual paths with constant and same fixed initial time $t_i$. Similarly for the final time $t_f$.

IV) Similarly, Hamilton's characteristic function $W(q,\alpha)$ should not be confused with the (off-shell) [abbreviated action functional](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maupertuis%27_principle) $A[q, E]$, nor the (Dirichlet) on-shell abbreviated action function $W(q_f, q_i, E)$. The abbreviated action functional $A[q, E]$ is usually only defined in the case of no explicit time dependence, cf. Refs. 1 and 2. In this case the (Dirichlet) on-shell action function

$$ S(q_f, q_i, T)
~=~S(q_f, t_f; q_i, t_i)\tag{5} $$

only depends on the time-difference $T:=t_f-t_i$. One may show that the

$$ \frac{\partial S(q_f, q_i, T)}{\partial T}~=~-E.\tag{6} $$

For a proof of eq. (6), see e.g. my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/19944/2451).

The (off-shell) abbreviated action functional $A[q, E]$ can be defined as a energy $\leftrightarrow$ time Legendre-type transformation

$$ A[q; E, t_f, t_i] ~=~ I[q; t_f,t_i] + E (t_f-t_i) \tag{7} $$

of the (off-shell) action functional $I[q; t_f,t_i]$.

In [Maupertuis' principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maupertuis%27_principle) we restrict to virtual paths with constant and same fixed energy $E$ but with free endpoint times $t_i$ and $t_f$. Formula (7) then becomes equal to

$$\begin{align} A[q; E, t_f, t_i]~=~&  \int_{t_i}^{t_f} p\dot{q} ~\mathrm{d}t, \cr p~:=~&\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}}.\end{align}\tag{8} $$

As a consequence, the (Dirichlet) on-shell abbreviated action

$$\begin{align} W(q_f, q_i, E) 
~=~& S(q_f, q_i, T) + E T\cr ~\stackrel{(6)}{=}~&
 S(q_f, q_i, T) -  T\frac{\partial  S(q_f, q_i, T)}{\partial T}\end{align} \tag{9} $$

becomes the $E\leftrightarrow T$ Legendre transform of the (Dirichlet) on-shell action function $S(q_f, q_i, T)$.

References:

1. H. Goldstein, *Classical Mechanics.*
2. L. Meirovitch, *Methods of Analytical Dynamics.*

Comment: Thanks very much I understand that now! thinking about it, it doesn't make sense to identify the characteristic FUNCTION with the Maupertuis FUNCTIONAL. I think I will need a little time to work through your answer and I will get back if any questions arise! cheers

Comment: Additional references: 3. M. Spivak, _Physics for mathematicians, Mechanics I,_ 2010.